# Access values from widgets in GXT

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gxt

I am new to Sencha GXT framework for GWT, how can i get values from GXT generated `TextFields` in order to send it to server?

```java
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.layout.FlowLayout;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.layout.FormData;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.layout.FormLayout;
public class Form extends LayoutContainer{
TextField<String> lastName = new TextField<String>();
    lastName.setFieldLabel("Last Name");
    fieldSet.add(lastName, formData); }
```

On client side how can i get entered values from `lastName` `TextField`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lastName.getValue();`

As per the [GXT TextField api](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/form/TextField.html)

Comment: COuld you help, how can i access TextField widget, from LayoutContainer?

Comment: try someLayoutContainter.getItemByItemId(java.lang.String itemId)

Comment: TextField<String> tf = (TextField<String>) layout.getItemByItemId("firstName"); Label lab = new Label();
        lab.setText(tf.getValue()); This line giving me nullpointer exception
        root.add(lab); how can I correct it?

Comment: Can you have a look, here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931701/access-values-on-widgets-and-send-to-server